# Why can't Jenkins find job object using extensible choice/system groovy choice parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I followed [Groovy to list all jobs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226941767-Groovy-to-list-all-jobs) to get a list of my job names, and got the exact "fullName" of my job, which is...

```
Microservice/build/feature%2Fdev-26387-split-micro-deploy
```

Now I have this to try to get all the successful build numbers for this job. The return values are just for debugging to see which value I'm returning, and I'm returning a list with the number "43", meaning, the getJobs() function returned a null, meaning it wasn't able to find the job object. Why?

```
import hudson.model.*

BUILD_JOB_NAME = "Microservice/build/feature%2Fdev-26387-split-micro-deploy"

def getJobs() {
    def hi = Hudson.instance
    return hi.getItems(Job)
}

def getBuildJob() {
    def buildJob = null
    def jobs = getJobs()
    (jobs).each { job ->
        if (job.fullName == BUILD_JOB_NAME) {
            // WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING???
            buildJob = job
        }
    }
    return buildJob
}

def getAllBuildNumbers(Job job) {
     try {
        def buildNumbers = []
        (job.getBuilds()).each { build ->
            def status = build.getBuildStatusSummary().message
            if (status.contains("stable") || status.contains("normal")) {
                buildNumbers.add(build.number)
            }
        }
        /// return buildNumbers
        return ["44"]
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        return ["45"]
    }
}

def buildJob = getBuildJob()
if (buildJob == null) {
    return ['43']
}
return getAllBuildNumbers(buildJob)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return hi.getAllItems(Job)` instead and it should work. Also, ensure your BUILD_JOB_NAME is set to correct job name. To check the job name, run `Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job).each { println(it.fullName) }` from Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Script Console

Comment: Thanks. The BUILD_JOB_NAME is correct, the getAllItems(Job) was the key.